# Precompile R packages for specific Linux flavor

Tags: r, package, precompile

We have established a simple local CRAN-like repository for R packages. There are many users, all of which use the same version of Linux.

Is there a way of convincing R to provide pre-compiled Linux packages instead just source ones? The compilation step takes a considerable amount of time for anyone using our repository. It should be possible to precompile and reuse the same binaries, since we can guarantee that the Linux version is consistent for all users.

How could one hack something like this together?

Comment: You might be interested in [cran2deb](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/cran2deb/) and [cran2deb4ubuntu](http://sites.psu.edu/theubunturblog/cran2deb4ubuntu/) as examples of this, though it may not be specifically helpful for you, as you may not be talking about a Debian-based distro. What distribution are you all running?

Comment: (That is, the answer to "Is there a way of convincing R to provide pre-compiled Linux packages instead just source ones?" is "Probably not," but the answer to "It should be possible to precompile and reuse the same binaries" is "yes," and the answer to "How could one hack something like this together?" will vary depending on your distribution)

Comment: @duckmayr CentOS 6 at the moment, moving to CentOS 7. Users do not have admin rights and install into their own local repos, so I do not think a Linux package is a good solution. I would like to rely on R’s built-in mechanisms if possible, so installing our packages feels just like installing from CRAN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the very narrow sense of "all of which use the same version of Linux" you actually have an option (that happens to be relatively littler known).  Create binary packages using *e.g.*

```
 R CMD INSTALL --build nameOfDirectoryWithSources
```

As `R CMD INSTALL --help` says it

```
--build           build binaries of the installed package(s)
```

and these are *not* `.deb` or `.rpm` alike packages: no dependency information or alike is added.  But they do *exactly* what you ask for:  save on compilation time.

I am not aware of a repository structure one can build of this though.

Comment: That gave me an idea - could I compile the package and convert it to “source package”,  “does not require compilation”. Then all the binary parts are just “payload”... I wanted to ideally have separate directory  in the repo to separate precompiled from genuine source, but at this point I am willing to hack,

Comment: I suspect you have not tried what I suggested :). Please do, it does pretty much what you described consequently.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested. It created a <package>_<version>_R_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.tar.gz for me.... which is GREAT. The part that I struggle with is - how do I upload it into our repository so it gets indexed and works fine, see what I mean?

Comment: That's what I wrote above: no repo support :-/ as there is no metadata.  But it will make for _very fast_ installation of the (versioned) package on a system "run-time identical" to yours.  Maybe best to think of it as a cache...

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it would do what I need.
Will try to submit a feature request for R for this usecase - should not be too hard!

Comment: Thanks. R extensions are mostly done "as packages" _i.e._ user-contributed and controlled.  You could _e.g._ wrap the call I showed and write out some additional metadata and build it up from there.